# Обмен данными между Bat и Node - Js

Tags: node.js, json, bat, txt

Есть задача

1. Нужно чтобы bat отправлял данные в скрипт или node js, а после скрипт сделал эти данные в переменные, к примеру const setting = данные
2. Чтобы bat получал данные с скрипта или node js посредством функции, или просто получал с любого другого файла, например txt, json

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это не учебное задание, это моё выдуманное в виде задачи. Просто мне так легче думать. А ответы на 2 варианта не знаю даже как и примерно написать честно

Comment: Вам принципиально, что бы это был отдельный cmd файл? Можно поднять процесс nodejs, который в текущей командной строке ждать приглашения на ввод данных. Вводите, процесс отрабатывает и заново выдаст приглашение на ввод. При этом фоновые задачи будут работать

Comment: @Виталий, неважно, чьё оно, главное, что нет попытки решения. По правилам этого сайта такие вопросы недопустимы и, если вы его не исправите, он, вероятно, скоро будет закрыт.

Comment: Пацаны , вы чё блин, я новичек а разговариваете так будто я всезнайка в этих бат файлах и этом сайте